# Schmidt decomposition manages to write a pure state using just d terms

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\psi$ $\in \mathrm{H_A}\otimes\mathrm{H_B}$ is a pure state and we can write a representation of $\psi$  like $\psi = \sum_j \alpha_j\otimes\beta_j$, where $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$
are un-normalized states for spaces A and B, respectively. How can I prove that the numbers of terms in such representation are greater or equal to the terms in a Schmidt decomposition? My attempt is to begin using the partial trace but I don´t get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach, I think, is to take advantage of the notion of matrix rank. Note that $H_A \otimes H_B$ can be canonically identified with $L(H_B,H_A)$ with the help of the (unique) linear map $\Phi:H_A \otimes H_B \to L(H_B,H_A)$ satisfying
$$
\Phi(\alpha \otimes \beta) = \alpha \beta^*,
$$
where $\alpha\beta^*:H_B \to H_A$ is given by $\alpha \beta^*(x) = \langle \beta,x\rangle \alpha$. Importantly, $\psi \in H_A \otimes H_B$ can be expressed as $\psi = \alpha \otimes \beta$ for $\alpha \in H_A,\beta \in H_B$ if and only if $\Phi(\psi)$ is a rank-1 linear map.

Now, suppose that
$$
\psi = \sum_{j=1}^r s_j u_j \otimes v_j
$$
is a Schmidt decomposition. Notably, this means that
$$
\Phi(\psi) = \sum_{j=1}^r s_j\, u_jv_j^*
$$
is a singular value decomposition. So, $\Phi(\psi)$ has rank $r$. Suppose that $\psi = \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j\otimes \beta_j$. It follows that
$$
r = \operatorname{rank}(\Phi(\psi)) = 
\operatorname{rank} \Phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j\otimes \beta_j\right)
= \operatorname{rank} \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j \beta_j^*
\leq \sum_{j=1}^k \operatorname{rank}(\alpha_j \beta_j^*) = k.
$$
That is, it must hold that $k \geq r$, which is what we wanted to show.